# Where does Apache Qpid GUI make changes on disk?

Tags: json, apache, qpid

I'm trying to delete a port interface on Qpid **without** using the Broker Management GUI.

Making the change manually (using the GUI) reveals that `config.json` is modified when a port is deleted (from using `diff`).

My code solution uses `sed` to delete the necessary lines from `config.json`.

This is not working as intended however, and I think another file needs to be modified.

I have `diffed` the entire `qpid-broker` directory, seeing that only `config.json` is changed using the GUI.

Is there a database, or some other change I'm missing to delete the port? I cannot use the GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use the REST API to customise the Broker's configuration.    There are a couple of examples in the documentation to help you get started, including a couple of command line examples using cURL.  The Web Management Console uses the REST API itself, so you can use tools such as Firebug to watch the REST interactions it makes for additional inspiration.

https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-java-6.1.4/java-broker/book/Java-Broker-Management-Channel-REST-API.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've looked at the REST API, but I am unable to use `curl` to send requests. `wget` is the only option, and this doesn't seem possible. I think I need to use `DELETE` to remove the http port on Qpid.

Comment: So you are trying to remove the HTTP management port?  Out of curiosity, why?    If want to customise the Broker's initial configuration, there are two command line options  to help.  --create-initial-config  gets a copy of the default configuration (the idea being you modify this by hand and then source control the result) and --initial-config-path to start a Broker from a configuration you provide.   See https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-java-6.1.4/java-broker/book/Java-Broker-Initial-Configuration.html

Comment: Thanks that helped. I've managed to remove the management port now. I'll mark this as the answer - the comments might help somebody else.